# Replacing column 2 in original with column 2 in new

Tags: file, awk, sed, merge

I have a file containing thousands of original results and a file containing hundreds of new results. Only column 2 of new is different from the original. I also need to keep original results that haven't been changed. How should I go about doing this? Is it possible to create a file3 containing the original results which did not change and the new results? see below for an example.

```
Original            New             file3  

1:1:1              2:5:2            1:1:1   
2:2:2              3:4:3            2:5:2  
3:3:3              5:9:5            3:4:3  
4:4:4              6:8:6            4:4:4  
5:5:5                               5:9:5  
6:6:6                               6:8:6  
7:7:7                               7:7:7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk**

```
  awk -F':' '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' Original_file new_file | sort
```

`Original_file new_file` - read both files

for each one of the files read line and:

1) `-F':'` - use `:` as separator

2)   `a[$1]=$0` - create a Hash that it's key is the first column and the value is the all line. if key exists run it over with the new value.

3) `for(i in a) print a[i]` - print the hash values

4) `sort` - sort results by order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the diff command between the old file and the new file.

`diff -y Original.txt New.txt`

```
Original             New

 1:1:1              1:1:1
 2:2:2         |    2:5:2
 3:3:3         |    3:4:3
 4:4:4              4:4:4
 5:5:5         |    5:9:5
 6:6:6         |    6:8:6
 7:7:7              7:7:7
```

For each line, if it contain this character "|" use the command `awk` to catch the value of new file. Otherwise catch the value of one of both sides, after all both are equals.

Try something how this:

```
number_of_lines_pipe=$(diff -y Orginal.txt New.txt | grep -e "|" | wc - l)
number_of_lines_without_pipe=$(diff -y Orginal.txt New.txt | grep -v "|" | wc - l)

for ((i = 1; i <= $number_of_lines_pipe; i++))
do
    line=$(diff -y Orginal.txt New.txt | grep -e "|" | sed -n $i'p')
    echo "$line" | awk -F"|" '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/\t *//' >> File3.log
done

for ((i = 1; i <= $number_of_lines_without_pipe; i++))
do
    line=$(diff -y Orginal.txt New.txt | grep -v "|" | sed -n $i'p')
    echo "$line" | awk -F" " '{ print $1 }' >> File3.log
done
```